# Tailwindcss is not working in my vite app

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css, vite

the following is my tailwindcss config file code:

```
`/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,ts,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}`
```

I am trying to implement tailwindcss in my vite+react app but the tailwindcss is not working, please help me to get rid of the problem

I tried to add tailwindcss in my vite+react application but its not working, my expectation is that   anyone would help me and fix this problem

Comment: Please provide more details, or even better a repro, so we can help you.

Comment: Did you follow all the steps from https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/vite?

Answer (score 0):

First, you follow the recommended documentation of tailwind with frameworks.
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/vite.
I am also using react+vite project here I attach my config file for tracking.

```
import daisyui from 'daisyui';
export default {
  content: [
    "./index.html",
    "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    colors: {
      white: '#FAFAFA',
      winterGreen:"#19FB9B",
      riverStyx:"#15191d",
      blackBeauty:"#27272A",
      black:"#000000",
      ruinedSmores:"#101314",
      skyline:"#96A1B5",
      coldGray:'#565656',
      coldGray2:'#393939',
      gray:"#A1A1A1"
    },
    extend: {
      fontSize: {
        'xxs': '0.5rem',
        'xxs1':'0.625rem',
        'xs':'0.75rem',
        'sm':'0.875rem'
      },
      fontWeight: {
        'light': 300,
        'normal': 400,
        'medium': 500,
        'semibold': 600,
        'bold': 700,
        'extrabold': 800,
        'black': 900,
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [daisyui],
}
```